# Q: Sonos Python Self Test error: No handlers could be found for logger "smapi"

Tags: python-2.7, sonos

I am trying to run the SONOS self test for a music service on Sonos.

After getting the dependencies, and filling out the config file, I try to run the python Sonos selftest, however it runs into an error and I have no clue what the underlying issue might be to get it running:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "smapi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suite_selftest.py", line 226, in <module>
    nightly_mode(parser.config_file)
  File "suite_selftest.py", line 51, in nightly_mode
    development_mode(config_file)
  File "suite_selftest.py", line 186, in development_mode
    fixtures.append(getlastupdate.PollingIntervalTest(suite.client, suite.smapiservice))
  File "/Users/thomas/Desktop/PythonSelfTest/smapi/content_workflow/getlastupdate.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.poll_interval = self.smapiservice.get_polling_interval()
  File "../../sonos-1.1.0.dev_r300235-py2.7.egg/sonos/smapi/smapiservice.py", line 465, in get_polling_interval
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 362, in getfloat
    return self._get(section, float, option)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 356, in _get
    return conv(self.get(section, option))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix already, forgot to add the Polling Interval in the config file...

Comment: Thanks. We just about to suggest you look at your config file.